# Address of an array declared inside a new struct

Tags: c++, c, compilation

inside a definition like this

```
typedef struct 
{
    myType array[N];
} myStruct;

myStruct obj;
```

can I always assume that ([edit] assuming proper casting will happen which is not the focus of the question here [/edit])

```
(&obj == &obj.array[0])
```

will return TRUE or the should I worry about the compiler introducing extra padding to accomodate the myType alignment requisites? In theory this shouldn't happen as the struct has a single field but I'm not entirely sure about this.

Comment: C and C++ are **different** languages and a comparison yields different types in both. But none of them has a standard constant or macro named `TRUE`.

Comment: I would recommend to use `obj.array` if you want to refer to the array and `obj.array[0]` if you want to refer to the first element in the array. Using `obj` to access the array will be harder to understand for outsiders.

Comment: Not sure about C but in C++ there can be no padding before the first member variable.

Comment: Even for C, there is no padding before the first member variable

Comment: If you are up to casting: **Don't!** Take the address explicitly, that makes your intention clear.

Comment: `&obj == &obj[0]` is ill-formed (type mismatch).  Either you're talking in pseudocode,  or cast both to `void *` to make the comparison.

Comment: where did you see this (&obj == &obj[0]) ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

With a proper cast, this will always return true.

From section 6.7.2.1 of the [C standard](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1256.pdf):

> *13.* Within  a  structure  object,  the  non-bit-field  members  and  the  units  in  which  bit-fields reside have addresses that increase
>   in the order in which they are declared.  **A pointer to a structure 
>   object,  suitably  converted,  points  to  its  initial  member**  (or 
>   if  that  member  is  a bit-field,  then  to  the  unit  in  which  it
>   resides),  and  vice  versa.   **There may  be  unnamed padding within a
>   structure object, but not at its beginning.**

Comment: Thanks for confirming through the C standard. And thanks also the other guys who commented (the ones who read it carefully, at least :-)

Answer (score 6):

According to the current C++ standard draft [[class.mem] §20 (N4527)](http://eel.is/c++draft/class.mem#24), emphasis added:

> If a standard-layout class object has any non-static data members, ***its address is the same as the address
>   of its first non-static data member***. Otherwise, its address is the same as the address of its first base class
>   subobject (if any). [ Note: There might therefore be unnamed padding within a standard-layout struct
>   object, ***but not at its beginning, as necessary to achieve appropriate alignment***. — end note ]

Whether `myStruct` is standard-layout, depends on whether `myType` is standard-layout. If it is, then what you're asking is guaranteed by the c++ standard.

Note that `&obj` and `&obj.array[0]` have unrelated pointer types, so the expression is not legal in c++.